# Problem in counting bonding pairs (elementary mean-field theory on the Ising Model)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, mean-field-theory

When the Ising model Hamiltonian 
$$H=-J\sum _{<ij>} \sigma _i\sigma _j-H\sum _i \sigma _i$$ 
is assumed ($\sum _{<ij>}$ is the summation over all the bonds or adjacent pairs of sites, $\sum _i$ is the summation over all the sites), I think it is known that the self-consistent equation in mean-field theory is given as
$$m=\tanh (\beta Jzm)$$
where $\beta$, $z$ are the inverse temperature and the number of adjacent bonds, respectively, and $m$ is the mean magnetization $\frac{1}{N}\sum _i\sigma _i$.

But I'm confused about its derivation.

1. When I replace $\sigma _j$ by $m$ for the mean-field approximation, 
   $$H_{MF}= -Jm\sum_{<ij>}\sigma _i -H\sum_i \sigma _i.$$
   Since the number of bonds is $\frac{zN}{2}$ (ignoring boundary conditions) and $\sigma _i$ in the first term doesn't depend on $j$, we can use $\sum _{<ij>} =\frac{z}{2}\sum _i$. Thus we obtain, 
   $$H_{MF}= -(\frac{1}{2}Jzm+H)\sum_i\sigma _i =-A\sum _i \sigma _i.$$ 
   Using this $H_{MF}$, $\langle\sigma _i\rangle$ is calculated as below.
   $$\langle\sigma _i\rangle= \frac{\mathrm{Tr}[\sigma _i \exp (\beta A\sigma _i)]}{\mathrm{Tr}[\exp (\beta A\sigma _i)]}=\tanh (\beta A).$$
   Imposing $\langle\sigma _i\rangle=m$, the self-consistent equation is found to be
   $$m=\tanh \left(\beta (\frac{1}{2}Jzm+H)\right).$$
   I suppose it contradicts the known result.
2. When I replace $\sigma _i$ by $m+(\sigma _i-m)$ and the ignore square of the fluctuation term, the same calculation yields the self-consistent equation $m=\tanh (\beta Jzm)$.

Are there any mistakes in the above discussion?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_field_theory#Ising_Model

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{<ij>}\sigma_i = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{z}\sum\limits_{i}\sigma_i=z\sum\limits_{i}\sigma_i$, no need for that $\frac{1}{2}$. If you want to say that there is an energy $J$ per bounding then you need to change that directly in the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation*}
H = -\frac{J}{2}\sum\limits_{<ij>}\sigma_i\sigma_j-H\sum\limits_{i}\sigma_i
\end{equation*}